# Java - Compare frequency of elements of a specific type

Tags: java

my task is to read a file and then print out the most 10 frequent words in the text file.

I have used the following comparator and it gives me correctly the first 3 most frequent words but then it kind of gets it all wrong and it only prints out 9 instead of 10.

Here is my comparator

```
import java.util.*;

class CompareFreq implements Comparator<HashElement>
{
    public int compare(HashElement x, HashElement y)
    {
        if (y.getCounter() > x.getCounter())
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my main:

```
        String[] temp = new String[100000];
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

        while (obj.hasNext())
        {
            String text = obj.nextLine();

            for (String t : text.split(" "))
            {
                set.insert(t);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("All words and the frequency:");
        set.printTableInOrderAndFreq();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Most 10 frequent words:");
        set.getMaxWordsFrequency(10);
```

Here is the output that I am getting

```
Most 10 frequent words:
to
the
of
their
they

caused
with
companions
great
```

The first 3 (to, the, of) words are correct, they are the most frequent in my text but then the calculations are wrong. On top of that I believe it is deleting on of the 10 words where you can see there's a blank row between the word 'they' and 'caused'

I forgot to post my HashElement class, here it is

```
public class HashElement
{
    private String word; // ordet
    public int counter; // antalet förekomst av ordet
    private boolean isActive; // behövs eventuellt för remove

    public HashElement(String theword)
    {
        word = theword;
        isActive = true;
    }

    public void increment()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public int getCounter()
    {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public boolean getStatus()
    {
        return isActive;
    }

    public boolean changeStatus()
    {
        isActive = false;
        return isActive;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: show me the class of set object, plz

Comment: @LêHoàngDững HashSet set = new HashSet(100000);

Comment: Is it java.util.HashSet? It not have method insert()

Comment: I don't really understand what exactly you mean, I have an insert method yes

Comment: @Sikablato you use a variable named `set` for which there is no declaration. You call an `insert()` on that variable. The `java.util.HashSet` class has no `insert()` method, suggesting that `set` is not a `java.util.HashSet`. You also call two other methods on `set` that are definitely not in `java.util.HashSet`. This is why questioners are so often asked to provide a *complete* example, one that can be compiled and run by people who are volunteering their time to try to help. We cannot tell what that class does, and in fact it's hard to know what your code does since we don't have all of it.